# Manipulate List with calculating column

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, networkx, calculated-columns

I'm using `iPython 2.7` and I want to analyze a production system as network.

Therefore, I'm trying to create a network out of a `csv-file`. The `csv-file` includes two columns. The first column is a representation of work orders; the second represents working stations. The work orders represent Modules. The working stations have to be nodes of the network.
Following the `data.csv`-File:

```
ORDER_ID,MACHINE_ID,
0,0,
0,1,
1,1,
2,2,
2,3,
2,4,
2,5,
2,6,
2,1,
2,7,
2,2,
3,8,
3,1,
4,9,
5,10,
5,10,
5,5,
5,11,
5,0,
5,12,
5,13,
```

As long as the `OrderID` has the same number, it is one module. So in this list are five modules. The algorithm for creating Edges is the first part of the network analysis. The algorithm creates edges while they are in the same module. The algorithm works and it isn't part of my problem. The following code has to analyze the Machine distribution in a module.

For example: The machine `ID` 2 is part of `OrderID` 2. So I need the solution 1 in my results, but machine `ID` 2 appears two times in `OrderID` 2. Actually my code's output is 2. `MachineID` 10 in `Modul5` appears two times, as well. My code needs an addition in the last `for-loop (Analysis)`. I guess the code needs a `if` check, that adds just a `machineID` one time per `Module(OrderID)`.

I can't find a solution, because of the interdependence of the two columns. 
My current code:

```
#Import Module
import networkx as nx
import csv

#Create Graph
g = nx.DiGraph()

#open File
Data = open("Data.csv")
csv_F = csv.reader(Data,delimiter=',') #open File "data.csv" 
Data.next()                           #skiping first row in file

#Algorithmus for creating Edges
prevOrder = -1
prevMachine = -1
Nodes = []                        #creating file for calculate sum of nodes
SumModul = []                     #creating file for calculate sum of moduls
for row in csv_F:    
    if row[0] == prevOrder:
        g.add_edge(str(prevMachine),str(row[1]))
    prevOrder = row[0]
    prevMachine = row[1]
    Nodes.append(row[1])
    SumModul.append(row[0])             # Add Index to List of Moduls
    QuaModul = len(list(set(SumModul)))  # Quantity of Moduls
Data.close()

#Node Reuse
print "Quantity of Moduls: "+ str(QuaModul)

#Sort List of Nodes to get Sum of sorted nodes 
QuantityNodes = []
for node in g.nodes():
    QuantityNodes.append(int(node))
    QuantityNodes.sort()

#Analysis
for sortNode in QuantityNodes: #for-loop for nodes
    NodeRU = [Nodes.count(str(sortNode))]
    for NRU in NodeRU:
        print "Node Reuse of Node: " + str(sortNode)
        print float(NRU)
        print float((float(NRU)*100)/QuaModul)
```

I'm expecting following results:

```
Qantity of Moduls: 6
Node Reuse of Node: 0
2.0
33.3333333333
Node Reuse of Node: 1
4.0
66.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 2
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 3
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 4
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 5
2.0
33.3333333333
Node Reuse of Node: 6
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 7
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 8
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 10
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 11
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 12
1.0
16.6666666667
Node Reuse of Node: 13
1.0
16.6666666667
```

Comment: what's the logic of your "distribution" and your code isn't clear: what's "g" and "add_edge"? we cannot help if you cannot show a small reproducible code. Try to simplify your "calculation" requirement as this is not the main problem you have, and you probably just want something like "groupby"

Comment: @Anzel - `g` is a networkx digraph - it's line 5 of the code, and networkx is one of the tags.  `add_edge` is one of the most common networkx commands.  Unsurprisingly, it adds an edge to `g`.

Comment: Pardon me guys. Hope its more understandable, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you unconditionally do `Nodes.append(row[1])`. Thus, each time a machineID is encountered it is added without checking if it was previously appended for the same Order.

So, the simplest solution I can think of to solve this, is to leverage the fact that orders are in order. You can make a dictionary that maps each machine to its last order. Then you only append if the machine was never encountered before, or it was encountered and its last order is different from it current order. Here is the part where I made changes to your code:

```
d = {} # Machine to last order dictionary
for row in csv_F:    
    if row[0] == prevOrder:
        g.add_edge(str(prevMachine),str(row[1]))
    prevOrder = row[0]
    prevMachine = row[1]
    #check that the machine has never been encountered before or that its last order is different from its current one.
    if ( row[1] not in d or (row[1] in d and d[row[1]] != row[0])):
        Nodes.append(row[1])
    SumModul.append(row[0])             # Add Index to List of Moduls
    d[row[1]] = row[0] # map the machine to its order
    QuaModul = len(list(set(SumModul)))  # Quantity of Moduls
Data.close()
```

**Hints for writing a better question** Your code was very difficult to follow, it took me a long time to understand your problem and I was lucky that I had already answered a question of yours about the same topic before. So, kindly mind the following when asking question:

1- Try to make your code more readable, for instance you can add some comments, for yourself and for us to be able to track what is going on.

2- It is good to post the code to be able to reproduce the problem, but try to think yourself, where the problem might be and where do you think it can be solved.

3- When you explain the problem try to relate the explanation to the code. For instance it took me a while to figure out that a modul is an order.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for your handy tips. I will follow them next time. the code works!